# c#: How to safely send multicast packets without interference?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, networking, multicast

Sorry if the title is hard to understand but I don't really know how to put it in short. Let me explain.

I am currently developing a LAN-filesharing university project.
Everyone running the application will have to notify others that they available for file transfer. My idea is to Join a multicast group upon launch, and send a sort of "keep alive" packet in multicast: with keep alive I mean that this packet will tell all the receivers that the sender is still available for transferring files, if other users want to. So e.g.: I'm running the app and it will send this packet every 50 s or so, and other people in my network running my application will receive this packet and keep me in their memory.

This is what the client does (this is just an example, not actual code), at this point of the app I have already joined the multicast group and set the destination end point:

```
//   Sending first data, e.g.: my ip address...
client.Send(buffer, buffer.Length, MulticastAddressEndPoint);

//   Sending other data, e.g.: my real name...
client.Send(buffer2, buffer2.Length, MulticastAddressEndPoint);

//   Sending other data, e.g.: my username...
client.Send(buffer3, buffer3.Length, MulticastAddressEndPoint);
```

From the official documentation I read that Send:

> Sends a UDP datagram to the host at the specified remote endpoint.

So I'm guessing that *I am* sending **3** datagrams.

My listener thread is something like this:

```
IPEndPoint from = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.IPv6Any, port);

while(true)
{
    //  Receive the ip
    byte[] data = client.Receive(ref from);

    //  Receive the first name
    data = client.Receive(ref from);    

    //  Receive the username
    data = client.Receive(ref from);    
}
```

Now for the real question:
Let's suppose that two people are sending these 3 packets at the exactly same time (with their values of course, so different ip address etc), and no packet is dropped and they are delivered all in the correct sequence (first ip, then name, then username). The question is: I have absolutely ***NO*** guarantees that I will receive packets in this order:

> packet1_A | packet2_A | packet3_A | packet1_B | packet2_B | packet3_B

instead of this

> packet1_A | packet1_B | packet2_A | packet2_B | packet3_A | packet3_B

am I right?
The only thing that I can do is pack all information in one single byte array and then send it, right? This seems the most reasonable thing to do, but what if my information exceeds the 1500 bytes of ethernet? My datagram will be sent in more packets, so would I experience the same "interference" or my NIC will detect packets belonging to the same datagram and join them again and then deliver it to the OS?

Comment: Yes, you're right. The better solution is to pack all information in one single byte array and then send it. Next data-packs need to contain some identification information about sender (i.e.: ip + username). So that the recipient knew from whom the data came.

Comment: If your intention is to share files, you´ll have to implement some application level protocol to make sure your clients receive the whole file, in order. It´s normally impractical to send whole files (unless very small in size) as one message (fragmentation under UDP can be a real headache) so a series of messages is normally used. Your protocol will have to save state about datagrams sent, datagrams acknowleged by the peer and a numbering scheme (so the client will know if messages are in order and complete.

Comment: @C.Gonzalez no no, of course files will be transferred via TCP, between 2 users or even more (I will start a thread for each connection). I will have to send the profile picture in the keepalive too, but I intend to compress it and make it very small.

Comment: @andrew Thank you! In the keep alive message, I may send a profile picture too, but I will make sure to compress it so that I won't exceed the 65KB maximum file size.